# Can't download reference attachment from MS graph API

Tags: download, microsoft-graph-api, email-attachments

I'm using graph API mentioned below -
"client.api(`/users/${data_body.payload.originEmail}/messages/${data_body.payload.emailId}/attachments/${data_body.payload.attachmentId}/$value`).getStream()"

it works fine for me if attachment type is "fileattachment" but this api is not working in case of "referenceattachment"
also I went through the documentation it says that **"Attempting to get the $value of a reference attachment returns HTTP 405."**

and it does not return contentBytes
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RDAZ.png)

site to refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/attachment-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RDAZ.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGrft.png

does anyone have any solution to get content data of reference attachment. if yes it would be great help !! Thanks in advance

---

GET /drive/items/{item-ID}?select=id,@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl

response =>
[click to open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RDAZ.png)

Here you can see downloadURL is missing in response

Answer (score 1):

The graph v1.0 endpoint doesn't have any support for reference attachments (other then showing you that one existing on an email). You need to switch to the beta endpoint which will provide the sourceUrl of the attachment in question eg
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/referenceattachment

eg

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages/..AA=/attachments/AAM..
```

would give you something like

```html
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('..')/mailFolders('inbox')/messages('..')/attachments/$entity",
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.referenceAttachment",
    "id": "..",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2022-04-11T23:53:54Z",
    "name": "User1.text",
    "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
    "size": 565,
    "isInline": false,
    "sourceUrl": "https://..-my.sharepoint.com/personal/.._com/Documents/Attachments/User1.text",
    "providerType": "oneDriveBusiness",
    "thumbnailUrl": null,
    "previewUrl": null,
    "permission": "other",
    "isFolder": false
}
```

You then need to take the sourceURL and download that via the applicable API for the reference attachment. eg in this example its Sharepoint so you can use the SharePoint API to download the file.

Comment: Still struggling to download file by sourceUrl . I'm using "GET /me/drive/root:/{item-path}:/content" API. but not getting the actual content.
Getting response as below.

Comment: GraphRequest {
  parsePath: [Function (anonymous)],
  httpClient: HTTPClient {
    middleware: AuthenticationHandler {
      authenticationProvider: [CustomAuthenticationProvider],
      nextMiddleware: [RetryHandler]
    }
  },
  config: {
    baseUrl: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/',
    debugLogging: false,
    defaultVersion: 'v1.0',
    authProvider: CustomAuthenticationProvider { provider: [Function: authProvider] }
  },
  urlComponents: {
    host: 'https://me',
    version: 'drive',
    oDataQueryParams: {},
    otherURLQueryParams: {},
    otherURLQueryOptions: [],

Comment: path: 'root:/bl.sharepoint.com/:w:/s/**some path**/EaWgGpZmH2BMkve8ac88NGsBrMOGjfiq0swxHky33PcOSg:/content'
  },
  _headers: {},
  _options: {},
  _middlewareOptions: []
}

Comment: Instead of getting the /content you usually want to get the downloadurl eg GET /drive/items/{item-ID}?select=id,@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl and then you can use that URL to download the file in a separate get request. This is important when dealing with a large file (eg you generally want to chunk the download)

Comment: Hey ,
I tried that as well but not getting downloadURL in response

Comment: with or without the /content that later should give a 302 with the downloadurl in the response but if you just look at the properties on the file you should get a downloadUrl  unless you not looking at the correct resource (eg you looking at the drive instead of the item etc).

Comment: yeah ! I wanted to download content from drive only. let me know if you have any other way to download it